# Transparent microprocessor. Ports set as imput or output

Tags: microcontroller, wiring

I have an electronic board which is formed by 3 microprocessors. The simplified schematic is as follows:

[image]

I'm triying to update my board so i can use 2 microprocessors instead of three. So the final result would be like this.

[image]

But before building a new board, i'd like to test my desing by using one of the boards shown in the first picture. So, the question comes here. As the second microprocessor is going to be there (electrical connections are not removed), what should I do with its ports in order to make it transparent? By transparent, I mean that it does not affect the rest of the circuit. Setting all of its ports as inputs and programming it with an empty while(1) would do the trick?

EDIT:

Microcontroller (1) is an AVR ATMEGA644P connected to (2) which is an AVR ATMega8. The comms are done by UART. Microcontroller (3) is a Cirrus Logic power meter which is connected to (2) by SPI.

What I want is to connect directly microcontrollers 1 and 3 using spi and that microcontroller 2 doesn't do anything at all. In the final design it will be removed, but i want to test my code using the prototype suggested in the second image.

Comment: Since you haven't told us anything about the circuit in question, I don't know how we could sensible answer. Your second diagram shows a connection between 1 and 3 that doesn't exist in your first diagram, though, so it's difficult to see how stopping 2 would help you there.

Comment: @NickJohnson look at my edit. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: not sure if it is clear yet... as far as I understand: (1) is connected via UART to (2) which is connected via SPI to (3). you want to make a new board that has a SPI connection between (1) and (3), without (2) in the middle. is that right? where are the SPI pins of (1) currently connected? if they are not connected to (2) there's no way to test that without changing the hardware.

Comment: If you lift the chip off the board, then it definitely won't be there.

Comment: You could simply disable interrupts and timers, or make it (the uC labeled as nr2) react to external clock signal generator (might actually require building an R/C generator in order to wake it up)

Comment: Let's say I don't have the right tools to lift the chip off. it's going to be there but i want to "anulate" its effects. I'll program it with an empty loop. But what i need to know is how to set the ports (inputs/outputs) or if it doesn't matter.

Comment: but is the connection between (1) and (3) there, on the hardware? if you "just" need the circuit to behave as if (2) was not there, just configure it with a program that configures all pins as inputs, and then put it to sleep.

Comment: I'll do the connections between (1) and (3) using some wires. That was my question, thanks! I just wanted to make (2) sleep in order to avoid electrical issues and other kind of problems. So, setting all pins as inputs and making it sleep would do the trick, right?

Comment: It might be worth updating your question. Explain that you will connect the SPI of 1 and three with wires, and you want to know how to program 2 so that it won't affect the signals, even though it is also connected to 1 and 3. I didn't get that idea from the existing question, I thought you wanted to use 2 as some sort of SPI bridge.

Comment: "the right tools to lift the chip off" ... unless it's a BGA, that would be a scalpel (SMD) or side cutters (through-hole). Then wire up the few pins that matter, if your through connection is simply SPI. Ugly doesn't matter on a prototype, as long as it lets you answer your questions, run your tests, and reduce technical risk. (If it IS a BGA, and you run into problems making it sleep, then I'd try a hot air paint stripper ... carefully!)

Comment: Would holding the processor in reset be sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Simply programming the MCU with an empty main() will do the job. All GPIOs will default to high impedance inputs, so they won't disturb the rest of the circuit beyond a little parasitic capacitance. The MCU will consume some power sitting there idly, too, but I'm assuming you don't care about that.